# Django doesn't create translation .po files

Tags: python, django, localization

I have my translation strings only in templates (stored in the project_dir/Templates), I tried running the `$ django-admin.py createmessages -l ru` both in the project root directory and in the app directories that use templates with trans. strings. It created folders locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES but the folders were empty. I tried to add the django.po files manually (with the syntax mentioned in the [l10n](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/localization) docs). And ran the createmessages -a and compilemessages commands. It created the .mo files, but the translations didn't appear in the browser.

1. As I created the .po files manually I had no lines starting with #. What should I write there?
2. My template files are in different folder than the .py files for apps. Should I put some extra links to them?

Comment: Have you checked that django has not set the lazy tag to the translations? Paste a fragment of your .po file to see what you have.

Comment: The .po files that I created were pairs of msgid`s and msgstr`s where msgid corresponds to a {% trans %} in a template.

Comment: Is your [LOCALE_PATHS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOCALE_PATHS) set in settings?

Answer (score 24):

did you try :

```
python manage.py makemessages -a
```

from project root and app ?

this should create a .po that you have to edit.
be sure to remove 'fuzzy' stuff everywhere.

then :

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

You need to **restart** the server

Comment: It does not create the .po files. It just shows `processing language ru` and that's it :(

Comment: weird. do you have gettext installed ? Also the templates must be  loadable with settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS to be detected. Also try adding a call to django.utils.translation.gettext in a .py file to see if it comes from the templates or not.

Comment: what does "remove fuzzy stuff everywhere" mean exactly?

Comment: After `makemessages`, the tools may mark some entries as _fuzzy_. These are strings that are similar but not exactly equal to other existing strings. This may happen ie if a string was modified slightly. Then `makemessages` will mark those for reviewal, and Django won't show those entries until the _fuzzy_ flag has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Django (e.g. 3.2):

1. in the root directory create folder "locale"
2. run command `django-admin makemessages -l ru`
3. update your language files (located in the locale folder)
4. run `django-admin compilemessages`
5. Configure the LOCALE_PATHS in settings.py, otherwise you won't see the translations:

   `LOCALE_PATHS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')]`

   `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'`

Answer (score 0):

To fix empty po files:

1. Make sure you did the needed changes for the templates as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code). Please make sure that you are checking the correct documentation version for your project.
2. You can add a `locale` directory in your `templates` directory and add its path to the `LOCALE_PATHS` list. (Optional, but helpful to make sure that the template directory is included in step 4)
3. Go to the project_dir (you should run the next command in a parent directory of the files to be translated)
4. Run the command `django-admin makemessages -l ru`